# Prooving that If the union of two subspaces is a subspace, then one of them is a subset of the other.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Just got a really bad grade for this answer. Can you help me understand what went wrong?

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $U$, $W$ be subspaces such that $U\cup W$ is also a subspace.
Prove that $U \subseteq W$ or $W \subseteq U$.
My proof goes like this:
Let $u \in U$, and $w \in W$.
We know that $U\cup W$ is closed under addition, so $u+w \in U\cup W$.
Therefore we know that $u+w\in U$ or $u+w\in W$.
$U$ is a vector space, so $-u\in U$. It's also closed under addition, so $u+w+(-u)\in U$, and therefore  $w\in U$.
Similarly, $W$ is a vector space, so $-w \in W$. It's also closed under addition, so $u+w+(-w)\in W$, and therefore  $u\in W$.

We claimed that $u+w\in U$ or $u+w\in W$, which we know is equivalent to $w\in U$ or $u\in W$.
So $U \subseteq W$ or $W \subseteq U$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Your "proof" has a big flaw: you only showed that for *some* $\;w\in W\;$ then also $\;w\in U\;$ , or for some $\;u\in U\;$ also $\;u\in W\;$ ...that doesn't prove inclusion in either direction...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the math in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

An idea for you with reductio ad absurdum:

Suppose that both $\;U\not\subset W\;$  and also $\;W\not\subset U\;$ , then there exist $\;u\in U\,,\,\,w\in W\;$ s.t. $\;u\notin W\,,\,\,w\notin U\;$ . But $\;u+w\in U\cup W\;$ , so...what ?